# Best company-backends lists

Tags: company-mode

I know this isn't the best type of question for stack... but I can't think of another place where it might get enough exposure.

So I really like company-mode, but sometimes it's annoying to have to manually switch to the next backend (company-try-hard is handy here). I've started playing around with grouped backends, and I can see some awesome potential. Unfortunately, I'm not happy with anything I've tried so far. I think this might be better set with hooks for different modes. Does anyone have some interesting company-backends lists that I could get some inspiration from?

I mainly use python (elpy), javascript (js3-mode), web (web-mode) and shell scripts if that helps.

Answer (score 15):

You can set a default `company-backends`, then use hook to append different backends to different mode.
Here is a way I config in my emacs.

```
;; set default `company-backends'
(setq company-backends
      '((company-files          ; files & directory
         company-keywords       ; keywords
         company-capf
         company-yasnippet
         )
        (company-abbrev company-dabbrev)
        ))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-to-list (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
                         'company-anaconda)))
(dolist (hook '(js-mode-hook
                js2-mode-hook
                js3-mode-hook
                inferior-js-mode-hook
                ))
  (add-hook hook
            (lambda ()
              (tern-mode t)

              (add-to-list (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
                           'company-tern)
              )))

;;;_. company-mode support like auto-complete in web-mode

;; Enable CSS completion between <style>...</style>
(defadvice company-css (before web-mode-set-up-ac-sources activate)
  "Set CSS completion based on current language before running `company-css'."
  (if (equal major-mode 'web-mode)
      (let ((web-mode-cur-language (web-mode-language-at-pos)))
        (if (string= web-mode-cur-language "css")
            (unless css-mode (css-mode))))))

;; Enable JavaScript completion between <script>...</script> etc.
(defadvice company-tern (before web-mode-set-up-ac-sources activate)
  "Set `tern-mode' based on current language before running `company-tern'."
  (if (equal major-mode 'web-mode)
      (let ((web-mode-cur-language (web-mode-language-at-pos)))
        (if (or (string= web-mode-cur-language "javascript")
               (string= web-mode-cur-language "jsx"))
            (unless tern-mode (tern-mode))
          ;; (if tern-mode (tern-mode))
          ))))
```

- for web-mode, you also can use package `company-web'.
- or shell script, there are other packages support completion, you can search for it.

Comment: Awesome thanks! this helped out a lot. I tweaked it a bit since I like using `elpy-company-backend` and I like `company-yasnippets` merged with other code completion backends. The one thing I can't figure out is how to get `css-mode` and `tern-mode` to turn off when not in their respective tags.

Comment: Also, the [question](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/407) you filed was also quite helpful.

Comment: Good you can find that. grad it can help you.